# Remotely from Chrome or IE page loads ~60seconds, from Firefox or IE on local machine - instantly

Tags: iis, sharepoint, firefox, internet-explorer-8, google-chrome

## The problem:

- If i access SharePoint from Windows 7
  with IE8 or Chrome5 - I must wait for
  like a **minute** to get a response. If i use other Windows 7 with IE8, just the same - just wait a **MINUTE**.
- If i use Firefox3.6 on W7 machine - page opens up
  **instantly**.
- Now switch to [IE rendering engine in
  Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10909/), you will have to wait
  just as with IE.
- Now i tried IE8 on XP SP3 - page
  opens up **instantly**.
- I tried IE8 on Windows Server 2003
  SP2 (machine on which SharePoint is hosted) - page opens up
  **instantly**.

## IIS6 Logs

I did request almost instantly from all 3 browsers and this is what shows up in IIS logs (first 2 entries for each browser):

### Chrome

Ok, IIS saw first Chrome request when i Hit enter in browser, but i had to wait long for things to move on

> 2010-06-01 05:**46:04** W3SVC1794621940
>   192.168.0.9 GET /sapulces - 80 - 192.168.0.186 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+6.1;+en-US)+AppleWebKit/533.4+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+**Chrome/5.0**.375.55+Safari/533.4
>   401 2 2148074254
>
> Loading...
>
> 2010-06-01 05:**47:07** W3SVC1794621940
>   192.168.0.9 GET /sapulces - 80 - 192.168.0.186 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+6.1;+en-US)+AppleWebKit/533.4+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+**Chrome/5**.0.375.55+Safari/533.4 401 1 0
>
> ... etc...

### Firefox

All Instantly

> 2010-06-01 05:**46:06** W3SVC1794621940 192.168.0.9 GET
>   /sapulces - 80 - 192.168.0.186
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+6.1;+lv;+rv:1.9.2.3)+Gecko/20100401+**Firefox/3.6**.3
>   401 2 2148074254
>
> 2010-06-01 05:**46:06** W3SVC1794621940
>   192.168.0.9 GET /sapulces - 80 - 192.168.0.186 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+6.1;+lv;+rv:1.9.2.3)+Gecko/20100401+Firefox/3.6.3
>   401 1 0
>
> ... etc...

### IE

I did hit enter when it was 05:46:06, but these are first entries in IIS logs

> 2010-06-01 05:**47:08** W3SVC1794621940
>   192.168.0.9 GET /sapulces - 80 - 192.168.0.186 Mozilla/4.0+(**compatible;+MSIE+7**.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+Tablet+PC+2.0;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E)
>   401 1 0
>
> 2010-06-01 05:**47:08** W3SVC1794621940
>   192.168.0.9 GET /sapulces - 80 - 192.168.0.186 Mozilla/4.0+(**compatible;+MSIE+7**.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+Tablet+PC+2.0;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E)
>   401 1 0
>
> ... etc...

Nothing to see in Event Logs.

## Fiddler

### IE

```
GET /dokumenti HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/x-shockwave-flash, */*
Accept-Language: lv-LV
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: serveris

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 1656
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 12.0.0.6520
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 07 Jun 2010 08:40:46 GMT
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

------------------------------------------------------------------
GET /dokumenti HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/x-shockwave-flash, */*
Accept-Language: lv-LV
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: serveris
Authorization: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl4II4gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAbAdAAAADw==

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 1539
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAACAAAAEgASADgAAAAVgonihccyI36f5i4AAAAAAAAAAIIAggBKAAAABQLODgAAAA9CAEEATABUAEkAQwBPAFYATwACABIAQgBBAEwAVABJAEMATwBWAE8AAQAQAFMARQBSAFYARQBSAEkAUwAEABIAQgBhAGwAdABpAGMAbwB2AG8AAwAkAHMAZQByAHYAZQByAGkAcwAuAEIAYQBsAHQAaQBjAG8AdgBvAAUAEgBCAGEAbAB0AGkAYwBvAHYAbwAAAAAA
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 12.0.0.6520
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 07 Jun 2010 08:41:49 GMT
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

------------------------------------------------------------------
GET /dokumenti HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/x-shockwave-flash, */*
Accept-Language: lv-LV
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAJgAAAAYABgAsAAAABIAEgBYAAAAHgAeAGoAAAAQABAAiAAAABAAEADIAAAAFYKI4gYBsB0AAAAPirSYl+w3M1gPelXA+mS9OEIAQQBMAFQASQBDAE8AVgBPAGoAYQBuAGkAcwAuAHYAZQBpAG4AYgBlAHIAZwBzAEoAQQBOAEkAUwAtAFAAQwCxt4kZryxtOgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC7gY8LTv2TqmFbggCo52sIVw8zy2V/s0ZHHFSqA0tiiGpcNplfJlok
Host: serveris

HTTP/1.1 302 Object Moved
Content-Length: 161
Content-Type: text/html
Location: http://serveris/dokumenti/default.aspx
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 12.0.0.6520
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 07 Jun 2010 08:41:49 GMT

------------------------------------------------------------------
GET /dokumenti/default.aspx HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/x-shockwave-flash, */*
Accept-Language: lv-LV
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 07 Jun 2010 06:45:23 GMT
Host: serveris

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 114839
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Sun, 23 May 2010 08:41:49 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 07 Jun 2010 08:41:49 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 12.0.0.6520
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated=80; path=/
Set-Cookie: MSOWebPartPage_AnonymousAccessCookie=80; expires=Mon, 07-Jun-2010 09:11:49 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=d2r5lj32dm4svg554sixwc2t; path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Mon, 07 Jun 2010 08:41:51 GMT

------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Chrome

But when trying to use Google Chrome, then fiddler hangs if i do not close chrome soon after sending request - all i see in fiddler is a flood (thousands) of 401 (unauthorized) responses.

## The question

[Similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/143610/ie-and-google-chrome-timeout-on-an-iis6-hosted-ssl-page-that-firefox-handles-well) has been asked but there is no response and i`m trying to access page without SSL and that happens even on GET requests.

Where do I look? Where would be the problem? Browser? OS? I don't even know what to think about.

## Just a note

Just a note about chrome's process isolation: I found it sad that while I was waiting that minute with Chrome, i could not use any other tab (i could switch, but i could not, for example, scroll or use any controls)

Comment: have you disabled all add-ins?

Comment: Just tried disabling addons but that does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out it had to do something with authentication.

I checked what is my authentication privider and i had (probably accidentally) set it to Kerberos. I changed it back to NTLM (what i'v suspected it would be) and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

A shot in the dark, but I wonder if IIS is correctly setting the Content-Length header.  The only way a browser really knows that it got all the data is to look at the Content-Length header, and read that many bytes, or it can read data and then timeout waiting for more.  And that one minute time sort of sounds like a timeout.

Maybe the Content-Length header isn't taking compression into account and is wrong???

Try running Fiddler in IE and see what it shows.

Comment: I`m not on site currenly, but I tried to VPN in my workplace (that is an internal site) and i tried opening my sharepoint site - it works very well (on IE and Chrome).
I will have to see if problem has auto-resolved or will i still have problems when i`ll try to open that web on site.

Comment: Now i`m on site, and it still does not work. It did work with VPN from my home, but not here. Could you see edited answer please? Added fiddler logs. Also take a note that when using Chrome with fiddler, my fiddler hanged as it got flooded with 401 (unauthorized) responses.

Comment: Answer/workaround found, thanks for assistance.